# How to return a specific value on the condition that many different values are returned?

Tags: oracle

So I have a query that is pulling x amount of rows. When the rows returned have different values I want to return 'n/a' when the rows return the same value multiple times I want to return a single copy of it.

Heres my code

```
SELECT 
e1.i_code as apple, e2.i_code as banana, e3.i_code as grape
FROM table_d d 
JOIN table_e e1 ON d.x_code = e1.g_code JOIN table_e e2 ON d.y_code = e2.g_code JOIN table_e e3 ON d.z_code = e3.g_code 
WHERE d.a_code = '12345'
group by e1.i_code, e2.i_code, e3.i_code;
```

the result of this query is

| apple | banana | grape |
| --- | --- | --- |
| m | n | t |
| n | n | t |

I want to modify my query such that when the results of any of these columns have different values they return n/a and if the results of these columns are the same then return 1 of them.

Desired result

| apple | banana | grape |
| --- | --- | --- |
| n/a | n | t |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can aggregate over the entire result set and check if the `DISTINCT` `COUNT` for each column is `1` and return that value or else `'n/a'`:

```sql
SELECT CASE COUNT(DISTINCT e1.i_code)
       WHEN 1
       THEN MAX(e1.i_code)
       ELSE 'n/a'
       END AS apple,
       CASE COUNT(DISTINCT e2.i_code)
       WHEN 1
       THEN MAX(e2.i_code)
       ELSE 'n/a'
       END AS banana,
       CASE COUNT(DISTINCT e3.i_code)
       WHEN 1
       THEN MAX(e3.i_code)
       ELSE 'n/a'
       END AS grape
FROM   table_d d 
       INNER JOIN table_e e1 ON d.x_code = e1.g_code
       INNER JOIN table_e e2 ON d.y_code = e2.g_code
       INNER JOIN table_e e3 ON d.z_code = e3.g_code 
WHERE  d.a_code = '12345';
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_d (a_code, x_code, y_code, z_code) AS
SELECT '12345', 1, 2, 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '12345', 2, 2, 3 FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE table_e (g_code, i_code) AS
SELECT 1, 'm' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'n' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 't' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| APPLE | BANANA | GRAPE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| n/a | n | t |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/DH5n_saT)

Comment: this works but is there any way to avoid the distinct? I want to reduce the cost